# Is there a way that I can "share" images by sending them to an HTTP endpoint?

Tags: share-menu, https

I want to make some hacky prototypes where I use my phone to collect data and then process it with a regular program. For this I want to share images with an HTTP endpoint written by me to execute arbitrary code.

Is there an application that supports a "share to HTTP endpoint" feature?

## Research

This thread talks about Tasker, https://groups.google.com/g/tasker/c/lI82IrDMq9k?pli=1, but it also talks about custom app manifests, which make me think this might be quite a lot of work.

Comment: Http is just a protocol that can be used in various ways, what you need is a combination of app and server which work together. The main question remains with who you want to share the images? Something like a online gallery you want to give access to someone? Dropbox and other file-sync tools have the feature to share files and folders with other users.

Comment: Well... I want to share the images with myself. Or specifically a program written by me that accepts files send over HTTP and does things with them. 

I am actually thinking of feeding the files into mechanical turk.

Comment: I would use Dropbox for sharing. Just place the files to be sent to the server in a special folder in your Dropbox account and install Dropbox client on the server that automatically syncs that folder and processes all incoming files. Dropbox sharing has the advantage that you are getting a secure authentication system so no-one else can inject files to your server. And the file upload can even get interrupted without problem.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable solution, assuming that dropbox has some sort of event system to tell me when a new file arrives. The other thing I had thought of was some sort of whatsapp chatbot.  I was thinking of adding a random number to the URL (and using https) for security, but that works too.